# R yearly returns from dataframe with date and close

Tags: r, quantmod

I have a data.frame `df` with date `df$Date` and a close `df$Close` column.
I am trying to get yearly returns but I am having problems

I tried

```
library(quantmod)
yr <- data.frame( periodReturn(df, period='yearly', subset='2008::'))
```

and also having date as rownames, but cannot get it to work.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What problems are you having exactly? Can you provide a sample of your data?  It will let us reproduce the specific problem you're having.  However, without that, just a description of the problem and the error that you see when you execute the second line will help a lot.

Comment: For instance post `dput(df)` or, if it is too big `str(df)` and `head(df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost works if you just convert to `xts`.  If you're having difficulty converting your `data.frame` to `xts`, then provide more info about your data as requested in the comments of your question.

```
getSymbols("SPY", src='yahoo', return.class='data.frame')
#[1] "SPY"
class(SPY)
#[1] "data.frame"
as.data.frame(periodReturn(xts(SPY[["SPY.Close"]], as.Date(rownames(SPY))), 
                           'yearly', subset="2008/"))
           yearly.returns
2008-12-31   -0.382805554
2009-12-31    0.234929078
2010-12-31    0.128409907
2011-12-30   -0.001988072
2012-06-04    0.020717131
```

Comment: @adam.888, you shouldn't have to convert it to xts. The function is supposed to do that for you, but there are 2 small typos in `periodReturn` that prevent if from working directly with data.frames. I have e-mailed a patch to the author.

Comment: @adam.888, The patch has been applied in Rev. 580 on R-forge.  You can check it out and build it yourself (or wait until R-forge builds it, or wait even longer until it is pushed to CRAN).  With this version, `periodReturn(SPY, 'yearly', subset='2008/')` will work.